# Core Prime G360T(5.1.1) soft brick TWRP issue

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, twrp

My main objective is to root the phone; as expected from an android newb. I bricked by phone, though this is a bit complicated than the usual.

Here's what I did. 
1. Apply Kingroot One-click root (from pc) 
2. Installed SuperSU = [failed to update]
-- checked (anyway) root from Root Checker = FAIL

3. Tried http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development/kernel-root-root-sm-g360t1-5-1-1-t3203522
   -- checked  root from Root Checker = FAIL
4. Tried installing TWRP (Odin method)
   (here's where things get messy)

a. Download mode (Vol up + home + pwr) goes straight to TWRP recovery
BUT
b. TWRP touchscreen controls do not work.

any solutions guys? I'd appreciate all the help! (And I'm also kinda desperate)

Answer (score 2):

Touch is not working in the official TWRP release for Galaxy Core Prime. Current solution is to install modified TWRP for G360T1, the MetroPCS variant. Find it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development/recovery-unofficial-twrp-sm-g360t1-t3208853). You should still be able to get into download mode again and Odin flash new TWRP.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development/recovery-unofficial-twrp-sm-g360t1-t3208853

Comment: just a note...main twrp functions work, things like OTG and rebooting menu doesn't. Kinda a WIP. If rooting doesn't work thru twrp,  try TrapKernel at http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development/kernel-root-root-sm-g360t1-5-1-1-t3203522  Came across your post trying to find my own solution. I am currently running twrp,  rooted,  de-samsunized,  and it's running smooth and clean.

Comment: Wow, that's good for you. unfortunately I had to get my phone "J-TAG"ed just to be fixed. Things went really haywire back then and I needed my phone pronto. I'm still on the lookout for stable G360T root procedures; but for now, I'll stick with an all stock setting. :D